# firemonkey threading on android show a black page

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

i used a httpd to request some data from internet

```
function requestToServer(lParamList: TStringList) : string;
var
  userDataString : string;
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  serverResponce : string;
  aobj: ISuperObject;
begin
application.ProcessMessages;
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
        lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
        try
          serverResponce := lHTTP.Post('http://domain.com/mjson.php', lParamList);
          application.ProcessMessages;
          aobj:= SO(serverResponce);
          try
             X := aobj['dta'].AsArray;
          Except
            form2.Memo1.Lines.Add('errr');
          end;
            if aobj['result'].AsString = 'lr_102' then
            begin
             form2.Label3.Text:='Saved token expired.';
             form2.Rectangle2.Visible:=true;
            end
            else if aobj['result'].AsString = 'lr_103' then
            begin
             form2.Label3.Text:='Auto login.';
             //load device data
             form2.allDeviceListData := X;
             form2.Hide;
             form1.show;
            end;
           // globalReachedServer:=true;
        finally
          lHTTP.Free;
          lParamList.Free;
        end;

      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin

        end);
    end
  ).Start();
end;
```

but after reach this function
the application show a black page and dont do anything until manually close

how can i do a web request at the background and with out hanging on fire-monkey !?
what a bout using REST is it better to access web service's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not thread-safe. Your thread is directly accessing UI controls without synchronizing with the main UI thread.  That alone can cause problems.

Also, all of the variables declared in the `var` section of `requestToServer()` should be moved into the `var` section of the anonymous procedure instead, since `requestToServer()` does not use them, so they can be completely local to the thread instead.  The only thing the anonymous procedure should be capturing is the `lParamList` content.

Try something more like this:

```
function requestToServer(lParamList: TStringList) : string;
var
  Params: TStringList;
  Thread: TThread;
begin
  Params := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Params.Assign(lParamList);
  except
    Params.Free;
    raise;
  end;
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var
      lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
      serverResponce : string;
      aObj: ISuperObject;
    begin
      try
        try
          lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
          try
            serverResponce := lHTTP.Post('http://domain.com/mjson.php', lParamList);
            aObj := SO(serverResponce);
            if aObj['result'].AsString = 'lr_102' then
            begin
              TThread.Queue(nil,
                procedure
                begin
                  form2.Label3.Text := 'Saved token expired.';
                  form2.Rectangle2.Visible := true;
                end
              );
            end
            else if aObj['result'].AsString = 'lr_103' then
            begin
              X := aObj['dta'].AsArray;
              TThread.Queue(nil,
                procedure
                begin
                  form2.Label3.Text := 'Auto login.';
                  //load device data
                  form2.allDeviceListData := X;
                  form2.Hide;
                  form1.show;
                end
              );
            end;
            // globalReachedServer := true;
          finally
            lHTTP.Free;
          end;
        finally
          Params.Free;
        end;
      except
        TThread.Queue(nil,
          procedure
          begin
            form2.Memo1.Lines.Add('errr');
          end
        );
      end;
    end
  ).Start;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, for connect to internet and grab data is better to use `CreateAnonymousThread` or declare thread with `thread.execute` !?!

Comment: @peimanF. It doesn't really matter since `CreateAnonymousThread()` is just a wrapper for `TThread.Execute()` (Indy has a `TIdThreadComponent` that is also a wrapper). A better question would be which is better, `TThread` or `TTask`. Either way, these kind of questions come down to personal choice.